# create new document on button click using app maker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

In google app maker new document should be created on button click and the saved document link should be available in the form to open it for further use..(same functionality as in share point).i am trying on this...help me with some answer to make it easy.

Answer (score 0):

I think this functionality you want is already available, you can see your AppMaker projects in Drive:
[image: showing appmaker projects in drive]